# CGI.pm header function to bring up the download dialog box

Tags: perl, cgi

I need to bring up a download dialog box from my cgi perl script.

this is what I have

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;

print header(-type=>'text/xml',-charset=>'UTF-8');
print header(-'Content-Disposition'=>'attachment; filename="FileName"');
print "<root></root>";
```

there is something wrong with the content-Disposition. I could not get it to work.

Comment: You are sending two headers. You can't call `header` twice.

Comment: i just changed to print header(-type=>'text/xml',-charset=>'UTF-8',-'Content-Disposition'=>'attachment; filename="FileName"'); and it seems to work now thank you.

Comment: @ikegami  You should make this an answer and reap the points :-)

Comment: @Len Jaffe, It wasn't a full answer. Feel free to put the effort and get the points.

Comment: It wasn't a full answer, but it was the correct answer :)